# Angular Material Table not allowing for drag and drop disable flag for columns

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am using angular material table with some of the following settings:

```
<table
    mat-table
    [ngStyle]="{'height': '600px'}"
    [dataSource]="items"
    multiTemplateDataRows
    matSort
    (matSortChange)="sortData($event)"
    [matSortActive]="componentSettings.header.sort"
    [matSortDirection]="componentSettings.header.order"
    cdkDropList
    cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
    [cdkDragDisabled]="!editMode"
>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
template.html:26 NG0303: Can't bind to 'cdkDragDisabled' since it isn't a known property of 'table' (used in the 'TableDataComponent' component template).
1. If 'table' is an Angular component and it has the 'cdkDragDisabled' input, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

Is there a way to disable column drag and drop with a boolean flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to disable sorting entire table, you can set `cdkDropListSortingDisabled`.

```
<table

    cdkDropList
    cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
    [cdkDropListSortingDisabled]="!editMode"
>
```

Or you can set `cdkDragDisabled` to child elements.

```
<table
       :
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
>
  <tr [cdkDragDisabled]="!editMode">
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Worked awesome! Can you direct me to the docs where you found this field? I was not able to find it in angular materials -> table -> api .. thanks.